# How to use PHP to get the value of a star rating widget?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have this star rating widget on my page, allowing the user to hover over the stars and select the rating and submit it.

This is the html and css :

```
<form method="post" id="star_review" name="star_review" action=">

<div class="rate_review">
     <div class="col-md-4"></div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                   <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <div class="skillLineDefault">
                                    <div class="skill pull-left text-center">Rate the Exam</div>
                                    <div class="rating" id="rate1"></div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                   </div>
             </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Submit </button>
</form>


<style>

.rate_review {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    position: static;
}
.rating {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

div.skill {
    background: #5cb85c;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: white;

    padding: 3px 4px;
    margin-top: -10px;

}

.skillLine {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 90px;
    padding: 3px 4px;
}

skillLineDefault {
    padding: 3px 4px;

}
```

JavaScript :

```
<!-- you need to include the shieldui css and js assets in order for the charts to work -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/css/light/all.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/shieldui-all.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
initializeRatings();

function initializeRatings() {
    $('#rate1').shieldRating({
        max: 5,
        step: 0.1,
        value: 0,
        markPreset: false
    });
    $('#rate2').shieldRating({
        max: 5,
        step: 0.1,
        value: 1,
        markPreset: false
    });
    $('#rate3').shieldRating({
        max: 5,
        step: 0.1,
        value: 2,
        markPreset: false
    });
    $('#rate4').shieldRating({
        max: 5,
        step: 0.1,
        value: 3,
        markPreset: false
    });
}
</script>
```

if there anyway that I can get the value of the rating so that I can store it on to my database after submit button click ?

I have provided a screenshot of how the star rating widget looks on the screen 
    [Screenshot](https://gyazo.com/b579c81951e21509afc099b182aa3a67)

Comment: [This](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/rating/javascript/api/methods/value) shows you how to get the value, and [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) shows you how to send data to your server.

Comment: Use $.post or $.ajax on the click event of the star and insert the value into the database that way.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, can I ask how would you send this across to the server ? is there anyway without using AJAX ?

Comment: Not without navigating away from the page... Unless that's not an issue? You could submit the information to a php script using the form action but that will navigate away from the page or at least reload the current page if you post it to itself.

Comment: Please don't think that I am asking too much, but could you show me a simple example of an Ajax that can be used for this scenario. Thanks in advance

Comment: You've been given the tools. The least you can do now is make an effort to use them.

Comment: If you want to help others then have a look at the answer I accepted 
;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to achieve this is by adding a function

```
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("myRate1").value = $('#rate1').swidget().value();
}
```

Then adding a Hidden text box in form like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="myRate1" id="myRate1"/>
```

and then calling this function [myFunction] on form's onsubmit event

Comment: hi, you're a life saver, this was a coursework due in 2 hours time, my teacher is scary and i don't want to get in trouble

Comment: also checkout the action attribute of your form, you forgot to type [ " ]( double inverted commas ). it should be action="" or action="somePage.php" rather than action="